# how to find which serial device is used for terminal output in embedded linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am using a i.MX28 board from freescale. I am writing linux applications for this device.
I plan to compile and load gdbserver on it to debug over serial interface. I am able to connect and login to the shell using hyperterminal or minicom but I dont know which tty device is default for terminal. How can I find which /dev/tty is being used?

Answer (score 0):

**w** or **who** will tell you the current sessions and which TTY is used for each one.